# which event get fired when sub-menu items open

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have designed a simple xaml which has a Menu called "File" in menubar. And sub-menu items are "New", "Open", "Save". Which event get fired when menu will expand / or open sub-menu popup windows? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called SubmenuOpened https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.submenuopened(v=vs.110).aspx. Refer below code.

```
 <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="File" SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_SubmenuOpened">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Save" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
 private void MenuItem_SubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```